# Powerbuilder extract EXIF

Tags: exif, powerbuilder

Good Day,
Would like to ask help,
if possible powerbuilder able to extract exif data or details on JPEG?

Thanks,
bolivar1985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, no, PowerBuilder (PB) does not have that capability.  You would have to write a COM wrapper for some other component, say a C#, and expose methods to PB that could be called.